# Serial comma in list of 2 items

Tags: commas, lists

When there are three (or more) items in a list, you write it like this:

> The British flag has red, blue, and white.

But do you do the same for a list with two items, with a comma before the "`and`"?

> The Canadian flag has red, and white.

Or, just

> The Canadian flag has red and white.

Which one is correct? Do different context allow the different forms? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just

> The Canadian flag has red and white.

no comma.

Comment: Wouldn't you say, "The Canadian flag ** *is* ** red and white" instead? Or "The Canadian flag has *the colors* red and white"?

Comment: @miltonaut I was just following the example given, not judging the grammar. Of course you are right.